# MapDb: is there any limitation for the number of maps

Tags: mapdb

I'm using mapdb 1.0.7 and my question is:
is there any limitation for the number of maps I can create with a single Db instance? Or is it theoretically unlimited.

I've tested to create 1.000.000 maps with 25 entries in each of it. This works fine. But is there any limitation?

Kind regards
Thorsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the answer in the mapdb google group:
there is no limit. But each opened map consumes under 1KB on heap. So I would recommend to keep it under thousands or millions.